# Clonezilla fails to find disk

Tags: syslinux

I have an ubuntu 16.04 , build 1.48 installed on my laptop with a dual boot windows/ ubuntu.

I tried using Clonezilla to clone my disk bit it failes to find "existing or unmount disk".

Please advise on any easy to use alternatives to Clonezilla?

Comment: Filezilla or Clonezilla?

Comment: @OrganicMarble -- he must mean clonezilla, filezilla is an ftp client

Comment: @marwan -- are you using it from a bootable CD?? it will only clone the disk if it isn't currently being used

Comment: I am only guessing: Maybe it helps if you boot into Windows, and shut it down or reboot and *avoid hibernation and also the semi-hibernation, which is called fast startup*.

Comment: @OrganicMarble : Clonezilla!  Fixed ! Thx

Comment: @ravery I am using it from bootable USB key, built using unetbootin and run on RAM  (boot option ) so that  I can save clone directly on the USB key.
However, all I have is a scan of available disks (The hard disk to clone and the bootable USB) and I've got no way to proceed further.

Comment: @MarwanB --  fixed excellent. please post an answer discribing the issue and how you corrected, in case someone else finds this post looking for help

Comment: Normally you should save your image of the source drive or partition(s) in a 'third' drive (not the live drive). I am not sure if Clonezilla will let you write to the boot drive, even with the `toram` boot option (maybe). I think most people use a hard disk drive connected  via USB or maybe sitting in a local server and connected via ssh and let Clonezilla write the image to that 'third' drive.